# Hashtable and String values error

Tags: android, string, hashtable

I have a master_string which has values that are retrieved from a pHp database. They are :

```
{"P":[["5"],["22"]],"AS":[["29"],["34"]],"DT":[["995"],["12"]],"AR":[["23"],["121"]],"SE":[["5"],["22"]]}
```

and after removing special characters, the string is now:

```
P:5,22,AS:29,34,DT:995,12,AR:23,121,SE:5,22
```

Now when I am trying to convert this into a Hashtable for some values, it should give me 2 values but it only gives me one. My code for this part is

```
String input = master_string;
Hashtable<String, int[]> result2 = new Hashtable<String, int[]>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:\\d+)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find())
{
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String[] fields = matcher.group(2).split(",");

    int[] values = new int[fields.length];
    for (int pqr=0; pqr<values.length; pqr++)
    {
        values[pqr] = Integer.parseInt(fields[pqr]);
    }
    result2.put(key, values);
}
```

Each alphabet is a key to its values after it until another key is found. What i found out that the result2 hashtable only saves the first value and ignores the second, any idea why this is happening?

P.S: the answer in result2 should be something like:

```
 P = {5, 22}
AS = {29, 34}
DT = {995, 12}
SE = {5, 22}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values contain `,` between digits so you need to consider it using

[`([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/uNXOgN/1)

`([A-Z]+):` : capture one or more alphabets and match `:` character

`(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)`: `\\d+` one or more digits

- `(?:,\\d+)*`  `*` zero or more occurrences of `,\\d+`

Output:

```
P [5, 22]
AS [29, 34]
DT [995, 12]
AR [23, 121]
SE [5, 22]
```

Comment: you sir are a lifesaver, kudos to you my brother from neighboring country!

Comment: @SaimMahmood thank you for appreciation , i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: and the website you mentioned in your answer is very nice, thanks again!